# Trying to solve a function defineBy which takes num as an argument and it should return a function that can take an array of numbers as an argument

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to solve a function `defineBy` which takes in a num as an argument. `defineBy` should return a function that can take an array of numbers as an argument. The returned function should map over the array and multiply each array value by num.

I wrote the function as follows:

```
function defineBy(num){      
  return function (arr) {        
    var defneBy = arr.map * num;

    console.log(defneBy);     
  }    
}

var defineBy2 = defineBy(2);

defineBy2([1, 3, 5, 7, 9]); -> [2, 6, 10, 14, 18]
```

I should get the output as defined above but I am getting just as blank function.

Comment: Maybe you should read the documentation for [the `.map()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: You should start off by properly indenting and formatting your code.

Comment: Your returned function doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`. It doesn't modify the array either. So no discernible results other than the value logged to the console (which would be `NaN`).

Comment: `map` is a function, and thus cannot be multiplied with a number!!

Comment: @clabe45 - Sure it can. The result isn't very helpful, but JS allows it...

Comment: @nnnnnn you're right :) NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be like:

```js
function defineBy(num){
  return function(arr){
    return arr.map(function(x){
       return num*x;
    });
  }
}
console.log(defineBy(2)([1,3,5,7,9]));
```